# Invoke in-built gingerbread screenshot facility via code

Tags: java, android-emulator, android

From Gingerbread onwards there is a built-in OS facility for taking screenshots (on non-rooted phones as well).

By pressing home and power button together and it also saves it to a folder on the SD card.

Is there a way to invoke this via code? The ability to take a screenshot is needed as part of my other app. There is an app named `screenshot-UX` that has a method called embedded screenshot capture, which I believe invokes that.

Does anyone know how to invoke the built-in Gingerbread screenshot facility or even how to use it? (with having optional parameters like save path, extensions etc..) as well as for non-rooted phones.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a built-in feature of the Android platform at the Gingerbread (2.3) level, although some OEMs did include it (Samsung, for instance, has you press HOME and BACK at the same time).  It was not introduced to the platform as something users could do with a button sequence until 4.0, where the sequence is now to press the Power and Volume buttons at the same time.

Even still, there is no public API via which developers can take screenshots.  The way that screenshot apps capture images Android devices is to read the frame buffer directly via the SurfaceFlinger in native code.

Comment: Thanks for reply..but for that we need to have root access!
Without root..need to have that..
and have you tried out screenshot-UX app..that app takes screenshot by a method called Embedded Screen Capture..do you know what that is then..
it works on my Ace(non-rooted)!

Comment: In 2.3, what changed is that root permissions are no longer required to access the `SurfaceFlinger` methods used for screen capture, but the overall method remains the same.  Applications now have to register the appropriate `sharedUid` value to access the method without root, but a native implementation calling `SurfaceFlinger` is still required.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks anyways..!
If you dont mind can i ask you for some useful link having native code to access the SurfaceFlinger....